# MySQL query: get rows of many to many relationship of items that are used together often efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, algorithm, processing-efficiency

I have a table tag_thread that associates tags with threads, just like here on Stackoverflow where one thread can have multiple tags and one tag can be used on multiple threads.

Now I would like to give a tag_id as an input to get tags that are often used together with the given tag (so to get relevant tags):

**Example table tag_thread:**

```
| tag_id     | thread_id   |
|:-----------|------------:|
|      1     |      1      |
|      2     |      1      |
|      3     |      1      |
|      1     |      2      |
|      21    |      2      |
|      3     |      2      |
```

**Expected output for the query:**

```
getRelevantTagIdsForThreadId(1): [3,2,21]

getRelevantTagIdsForThreadId(2): [1,3]

getRelevantTagIdsForThreadId(3): [1,2,21]
```

So the query should search for the given tag_id, then take the associated thread_id`s, collect the tag_id`s of the thread_id`s received in the step before and order them by how often the tag_id was found.

I already have a working query, however, it is not efficient at all and thus doesn't work properly for larger tables:

```
select `t2`.`tag_id` 
from `tag_thread` as `t1` 
    inner join `tag_thread` as `t2` 
    on `t1`.`thread_id` = `t2`.`thread_id` 
        and t1.tag_id = :tagId 
    where t2.tag_id <> :tagId2 
group by `t2`.`tag_id` 
order by count(t2.tag_id) desc
```

Any idea for an efficient solution? I would be okay with limiting the number of tags that are looked at in the first place, too.

---

**result of SHOW CREATE TABLE tag_thread:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tag_thread` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `thread_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=38496 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: Show us some sample data and expected output ? What have you tried so far; show us your attempted queries; the time taken by them and `EXPLAIN..` plan for them.

Comment: Suitable indexes should handle this well

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I edited the post accordingly, thank you.

Comment: @Strawberry looking at my query, which fields should be indexed?

Comment: @Hillcow I am not familiar with Laravel; in Raw SQL term, how does your query string look like ? I am seeing `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` in the query, so maybe that can be optimized away. Secondly, what all indexes are already defined on your tables ? Can you add the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tag_thread` to the question.

Comment: @Hillcow add two individual indexes `tag_id` and `thread_id`. That should be enough for your case. Another optimization tip: You can get rid of `id` (auto-increment key), if the combination of `tag_id` and `thread_id` is going to be unique. In the case,  you just need to define `thread_id` and `tag_id` combination as the Primary key.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I just edited my post to show you the raw SQL as well. I cannot get rid of `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`, because by using these I can see which tags are most often used together.

Comment: @Hillcow I figured that out with the latest edit of yours. I have suggested two indexes. Try them out. If that works, then you can look at the next optimization tip of getting rid of the surrogate column `id`

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Woah! I knew about indexes but I didn't think it would make that much of a difference. Thank you so much, it works flawlessly now.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Actually, I have one more question. How would I have to change the query so that it just looks at the first 20 thread_ids instead of all? I tried to put a `LIMIT ` after the `where` clause, but that didn`t change anything.

Comment: @Hillcow in order to get count properly, it will have to look at all the joined rows (that part you cannot limit); but you restrict the amount of tag_ids you get at the end (to optimize network burden). Put a `limit 20` at the very end after `order by` clause.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Sure, but let's say I don't want to get the count of all rows but only a limited amount of rows?

Comment: @Hillcow I am unable to visualize your requirement; some sample data (showing ignored rows) and then corresponding expected output would help.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Let´s take the sample data from above. I want to be able to set a limit of 1 for example. Then the expected output of `getRelevantTagIdsForThreadId(1)` is `[2,3]`, because it only looks at the first `thread_id` (1).